importing multiple Fspy cameras messes existing perspective
I was trying to build a jet, using a reference image imported through fspy but when im done modelling using the first reference and want to import another fspy perspective, doing that changes some parameter of the first camera which misaligns the first perspective.
The perfectly aligned view. 
The view after importing a second camera.


I'm not familiar with fspy but I reckon when you "import another fspy perspective", it either imports a new camera object into your scene or changes the properties of your scene's active camera.
In the first case, maybe what you see isn't your original camera's perspective but the new one's. You can select any camera and press Ctrl Alt numpad 0 to set that camera as active and set the viewport to its viewpoint.
In the second case, you can probably add a new camera before importing, set this one as active via the above shortcut, and then import.

The Fspy adds another camera to the scene with the positioning + FOV adjusted to a particular reference image. The issue is that the moment I add another camera through fspy, the first one changes in some way which disturbs its alignment. This isnt an issue about active camera.
